# Looking for older versions of NetBeans platform source code

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm looking for 3.5.x or 3.6 source code for the NetBeans platform. I have tried to connect to the CVS repos listed on the NetBeans website, but I don't think they are up any more. Does any have the code or know where I can pull it from?

Comment: I started using Netbeans around that time and I don't even remember if there was a Netbeans Platform back then. Tried the mailing list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this FAQ](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqGeneralWhereIsPlatformHowToBuild), the Platform code is not separated from the IDE code, they are just different builds.

The [mercurial repository](http://netbeans.org/community/sources/hg.html) seems to go all the way back to 1999.

The tags [listed here](http://hg.netbeans.org/main/tags) are not very consistent; there is a `release35R_base` in 2003 but I don't see something like `release36`. Maybe with the information contained in the releases available in [the archive](http://www.netbeans.info/downloads/dev.php) you could see which date corresponds to each release.

Hope this helps.

Oh, and [Hg init](http://hginit.com/) by Joel Spolsky is very good if you have not used mercurial before.

Comment: Yes, it seems to point to the same page I found as `http://www.netbeans.info/downloads/dev.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [link](http://netbeans.org/community/sources/structure.html?print=yes) Skimming over the text - apparently the releases are stored in a repository called Mercurial. You'll need to agree to their T&C's before downloading anything though